# Rotating, transitioning placeholder text with Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, placeholder

I have a simple text input. I want the input to have a placeholder that rotates through various values, where there is some sort of transition between the values.

For example, the placeholder starts as "peach", then 1 second later, that fades out and "mango" fades in, then that fades out and "banana" fades in, and so on.

What is the best way to do this? I don't believe it is possible to fade the placeholder with JS, though it is possible to change the value with JS. Maybe there is a way to do this with pure CSS that is better, anyway?

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: You can simply fade text with [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading), for text rotating use `transform: rotate(x deg);`

Comment: Classes like :-moz-placeholder are pseudo classes, which are not part of the DOM. By rotating I mean the text is alternating.

Comment: And I just tried using the CSS animation to do it, not working.

Comment: And what is the problem with creating overlay on top of that input?

Comment: That would work, but there may be a better solution.

Comment: How is this question too broad? My goal is clearly explained. I just solved this problem and I came back here to post my solution, but this is now on hold. If the question is too broad, please, at least one person, specify before flagging the question.

Answer (score 1):

Input placeholders can't be faded because they can't be styled (some browsers might allow this via extensions or [vendor-specific rules](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/) though, and you can simulate fading by using RGBA colors - animating the alpha value over time or tweening the color value towards the input background color), but you can change their text easily.

Here's an example I quickly sketched up for you:

```js
var delay = 1000;
var vals = ['peach', 'mango', 'banana'];
var input = document.getElementById('i');

for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    set(vals[i], i * delay);
}

function set(v, d) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            input.setAttribute('placeholder', v);            
        }, delay * vals.length);
    }, d);
}
```

```html
<input id="i" placeholder="starting" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to build off of this and see if I can get something working.

Comment: I ended up using something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3tFG/843/

Comment: Very nice! I think you made the most out of the placeholder.